# I have a weird error that pops up when I compile referring to std::ostream

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

the error makes no sense to me, I've done stuff like this before and followed it to a tee but now it just pops up.

```
#ifndef MATRICA_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MATRICA_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#define MAX_POLJA 6
using namespace std;

class Matrica {
private:
short int **mtr;
short int **ivicaX;
short int **ivicaY;
int lenX, lenY;
public:
Matrica(short int, short int);
~Matrica();

int initiate_edge(const char *, const char *);
short int get_vrednost (short int, short int) const;
short int operator = (const short int);
int check_if_fit(int *);

friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Matrica&) const; // HAPPENS HERE <====
};

#endif // MATRICA_HPP_INCLUDED
```

this is the error:

`error: non-member function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrica&)' cannot have cv-qualifier|`

Comment: delete the last `const` in your `friend` operator. `friend`s are free functions, not member functions, so they do not have `this` pointer, thus there is no point of making `this` a `const`. See my answer

Comment: @Fureeish that should be an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Matrica&) const;
```

You declare `ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Matrica&)` as `friend`, which makes it a **free function**, not a **member function**. Free functions do not have the `this` pointer, which is being affected by `const` modifier at the end of function declarations. It means that if you have a free function, you cannot make it a `const` function, since there is no `this` pointer to be affected by it. Simply delete it like so:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Matrica&);
```

And you are ready to go.